How to make windows toast notification unmutable on windows 11
I found out Windows security toast notification are not dismissible mutable, and it seems no other app are able to do so. How does it managed to do that?

There is an old post about this question, but it's 8 yr old (so it's at most windows 10) and I've never noticed this on windows 10.

You can dismiss it if you own it, obviously, using ToastNotifier.Hide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotifier.hide

@SimonMourier Did you even read my question?

Yes I did, if my comment isn't relevelant please explain what you need exactly, and it doesn't prevent you to be polite

@SimonMourier My apology. I want my user to NOT able to dismiss my app's toast notification, that is it should gray out "turn off all notification from ..." item in the right-click context menu, just like what is shown in the screenshot.

Why do you want to annoy your users on purpose? Is your application the most important in the world?

@Anders This is a requirement from my PM, not something I can argue with. If it's possible, making it a windows native notification could already be better than I rolling out my own implementation

I bet somebody got a really nice bonus for that feature and Why is there no programmatic access to the Start menu pin list?

Windows security toast notifications are designed to be persistent and not dismissible by default. This is because they often contain critical security information that Microsoft wants to ensure users see and address.
For UWP applications, it is not possible to disable "turn off notifications", even the latest Important Notifications in WinUI3 can also be turned off.
